# How to communicate between embedded jetty handler thread and other threads such as the main thread

Tags: android, jetty, ipc

I am embedding a jetty server inside my android service. There are other threads in that same service and I would like those other threads to be able to send and receive variables/messages to/from the jetty thread (handler).

I understand communication between my other threads but am having difficulty figuring how to communicate to the jetty thread

Thank You!

Patrick

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You should paste the code in! :)

Comment: I have comunication working between the threads and processes I implemented myself. I use Messenger/bind and it works well. But I cannot wrap my head around comunicating with the Jetty handler. I am new to Android. I come from a c/c++ background and used to shared memory for ipc. I tried Android MemoryFile cannot see how to use this between processes if you are not able to at least pass the file descriptor. My problem is I cannot see how to talk at all to the Jetty handler thread, even to pass something like a file descriptor.